# Logitech Mouse Defocusing Issue Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse

Specs
OS: [Main Machine] Windows 10 Pro(1803) / [VM] Windows 10 Student(1709 - Build 16299.309)
Processor: Intel i5-7600K
Mainboard: ASUS PRIME Z270-A LGA1151
RAM: 16GB
Graphics: nVidia 1070
Hard Drive: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB
Mouse: Logitech G502
Keyboard: Razr BlackWidow Chroma

The basic issue I am having is that my mouse appears to be defocusing whatever I attempt to click on intermittently. It will last for medium periods of time (not able to actually time it, but definitely longer than a minute). My work-around (which only partially works) is to press CTRL+ESC a few times, which usually is enough to let me click on the application I want.

The Windows Notification Menu items are almost always unclickable regardless of whether I've done the CTRL+ESC, or even if I can click at that point other applications that I have up.

This only started happening a couple weeks ago, but appears to be limited to the Windows experience (when playing a full screen game, I did not notice any issues).

Tried several google searches, which yielded some of the suggestions below, but most were 5+ years old (Related to VISTA or Windows 7) or related to upgrades to Windows 10. I also tried with another much older Logitech mouse, and had the same issues.

The VM windows version has also been included, as I experience the same issue on it as the main machine.

Things I have tried:
- Booting in Safe Mode with Networking
- Uninstalling the driver through Device Manager, reinstalling it
- Uninstalling the driver through Device Manager, and restarting the PC
- Installing Drivers from Logitech's Website onto the PC
- Attempted to Update the drivers to Logitech's Website
- Run the System File Checker
- Completed the Windows Reset (Both Options: Keeping / Removing Files)
- Fresh Windows Installation
- Ran Powershell Script to Re-registered Windows Apps
- Msconfig (disabled all Non-Windows Services)

Comment: Have you installed the latest logitech mouse software?

Comment: Yes. Downloaded yesterday from the Logitech Website.  "Logitech Gaming Software v8.98.234"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was the physical mouse, not a driver / OS issue. Using the Logitech software, I unassigned all of the mouse keys except the right / left buttons.

Immediately after doing that, all of the issues I was experiencing stopped. Then I proceeded to re-assigning the keys, and it was the first key I re-assigned was the culprit (the "back" button).

Wish I had come across the post that suggested that a lot earlier and saved myself all the grief.